# Solving set of equations efficiently

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I am learning math (calculus) by myself and for one specific exercise I have to solve a set of equations. I try to do it without any digital tools, but the task seems very daunting to me, so I am wondering: what is the most time-efficient way to solve this set of equations? My "normal" strategy would be to simply write it all out until I can write certain variables in terms of other variables and fill in that result. This is it:

$A(t-1)^2(t+1)^2+B(t-1)(t+1)^2+C(t+1)^2+D(t-1)^3(t+1)+E(t-1)^3=1$

This will give us a function of $t^4$ which is $0$, a function of $t^3$ also $0$, a function of $t^2$ also $0$, a function of $t$ also $0$ and a function of constants which is $1$.

The task seems rather daunting to me. So what is the most efficient way to solve this set of equations without use of digital tools?

Thanks!

PS, any jokes about lacking willpower are also most welcome

Comment: I only see one equation. This looks like an interpolation problem. What other equations do you have?

Comment: The variables of the set of equations are A,B,C,D and E. We have five equations: one as a function of t^4 etc...

Comment: Are you solving for $t$ for given $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ and $E$? Or are you trying to solve for $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ and $E$ such that the polynomial  is the constant polynomial $1$? (The former question reduces to the long and tedious process for finding the roots of a quartic equation. The latter reduces to linear algebra.)

Comment: @GambitSquared Writing it for $\,t=\pm 1\,$ gives $\,C,E\,$ directly, so you are left with $3$ variables to solve for.

Comment: @RobArthan the latter

Comment: After using dxiv's suggestion, you have to multiply out to get the coefficients of $1$, $t$, $t^2$, $t^3$ and $t^4$ as linear functions of $A$, $B$ and $D$ and then solve the resulting system of linear equations. (The best joke I can think of is very feeble: it requires a certain amount of will**power** to calculate the coefficients of the **powers** of $t$ $\ddot{\smile}$.)

Comment: @RobArthan Yes, is this really the most efficient way? First multiplying out is already tedious and then solving the system of linear equations is also tedious. It's not that I am lazy, it's just that I wonder about more efficient ways to solve.

Comment: @GambitSquared You could pick $3$ more (small) values for $t$ then solve the system (assuming you were lucky enough to have picked values such that the resulting equations are independent).

Comment: As well as xdiv's first observation, you can also read off before you multiply out that $D = -A$  (coefficient of $t^4$) and that $B = -E$ (coefficient of $t^3$). That reduces it to a system of linear equations in one unknown, so you can find the answer by just looking at one other value of $t$, say $t = 0$. However, you still have to multiply out or check on 2 more values of $t$ to check that the answer works.

Comment: @RobArthan D is also one of the coefficients of t^3

Comment: You're right. So looking at one other value will give you the relation between $A$ and $B$. There is no "royal road" here: the general case of this question requires you to do the algebraic grunt work and we are just lucky (or unlucky as I was) if we can find shortcuts.